# If Date is empty format_date() returns NaN/NaN/NaN insted of no value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery autocomplete onselect it is showing data in different text field. I am showing formatted date in `#dob` and `#anniversery`  by using `format_date()` function

```
select: function(event, ui) {
                        $("#customerId").val(ui.item.id);
                        $("#customerName").val(ui.item.value);
                        var datefield = new Date(ui.item.dob);
                        $("#dob").val(format_date(datefield));
                        var datefield1 = new Date(ui.item.anni);
                        $("#anniversery").val(format_date(datefield1));
                        $("#address").val(ui.item.address);
                        $("#mobNo").val(ui.item.mobno);
                    },
                 });
                function format_date(dt) {
                    alert(dt);
                   var dd = dt.getDate();
                    var mm = dt.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
                    var yyyy = dt.getFullYear();
                    if (dd < 10) {
                        dd = '0' + dd;
                    }
                    if (mm < 10) {
                        mm = '0' + mm;
                    }
                    dt = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
                    return dt;
                }
            });
```

Above code is working properly if `ui.item.dob` and `ui.item.anni` is not null.
In case of null it is showing `NaN/NaN/NaN`
If date value is empty it should not show anything in textbox.

`alert(dt)` prints Invalide date.

How to resolve this.

Comment: @limelights there's a difference between not having as date and having a date instance that's invalid.  If you call `new Date("hi")` you get back a sort-of "zombie" invalid date instance.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that too, I was a bit too hasty. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether a Date instance is an invalid date by checking one of the properties for `NaN`:

```
function format_date(dt) {
  if (isNaN(dt.getFullYear())) return "";
  // ...

}
```

Comment: I tried ` var timestamp = Date.parse(dt);
                    if (isNaN(timestamp) == false) {
                        alert("dt is null");
                        return "";
                    }' why it was not working

Comment: @xrcwrn If you pass `Date.parse()` an invalid date instance, it returns `NaN`. Therefore `isNaN()` in that case will return `true`, not `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, check that the Date object is okey using isNaN function. Also, there's an easier way of formating the date as you want, with out all the ifs:

```
function format_date(dt) {

    if(isNaN(dt.getTime()) return "";

    return dt.getFullYear + '/' + String('00' + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + String('00' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2);

}
```

Also good to know is that initializing a Date object like `var datefield = new Date(ui.item.dob);` has a bit poor browser support (

A more safe way of doing it is to initialize the Date object without any proporties, `var datefield = new Date();` and the using the Date `set*()` functions to set the time. A whole lot more code, but if you need it to work in old browsers...

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/HMb68/

```
var inDateTime = '2014-07-26 17:52:00',
    inDateTimeSplit = inDateTime.split(' '),
    inDateParts = inDateTimeSplit[0].split('-'),
    inTimeParts = inDateTimeSplit[1].split(':'),
    outDate = new Date;

outDate.setFullYear(parseInt(inDateParts[0], 10));
outDate.setMonth((parseInt(inDateParts[1], 10) - 1));
outDate.setDate(parseInt(inDateParts[2], 10));

outDate.setHours(parseInt(inTimeParts[0], 10));
outDate.setMinutes(parseInt(inTimeParts[1], 10));
outDate.setSeconds(parseInt(inTimeParts[2], 10));
outDate.setMilliseconds(0);

console.log(outDate);
```